# Why do some docker images have binary blob layers and some have layer.tar files?

Tags: docker, image, dockerfile, containers

I'm examining several container images to satisfy cyber security compliance for my project. Some of the docker container image have layers that look like this:

```
.
├── 002dd465768a1e98e3ed60c93a146544b126c08c9698ec21e5c2278cdc0da9b2
│   ├── VERSION
│   ├── json
│   └── layer.tar
├── 0fe7348ffe3808506392a882b1a169e31b567b0ea6a74030fca23d122666bd2b
│   ├── VERSION
│   ├── json
│   └── layer.tar
├── 1fb1a002b9e7b38da24e7382886b35027836caf8e51dc7f3b2561ef02d4a77a3.json
├── manifest.json
└── repositories
```

I can unpack the layer.tar files in each layer and see the file system contents. This is good because it makes it easy for me to explain to the cyber folks what is contained in the image.

However, other container images look like this:

```
.
├── blobs
│   └── sha256
│       ├── 05f925e80df95fd593f4294e1a1b37a8e3a46de297ff47530a3fe7594cd41e24
│       ├── 070bff1412567be65814c47fde966b864de43ab541075bcdcf66135ecde7d916
│       
├── index.json
├── manifest.json
├── oci-layout
└── repositories
```

Where each of the layers are a binary blob file, and I'm not able to easily examine and show the cyber folks the content.

Why are the two container images different? I built both images with the same version of docker (Docker version 25.0.2, build 29cf629) with no extra options, just:

```
docker build -t image_name:image_tag ./
```

Then I saved the images to a tar file to send them to the cyber security staff:

```
docker save image_name:image_tag > image_name.tar
```

Can anyone help explain or point me to documentation that shows why the images look so different when un-tar them?

Answer (score 1):

The first one with layer.tar is docker archive image.
The second with blobs/sha256 is OCI image.
https://snyk.io/blog/container-image-formats/